# error: illegal start of type

Tags: java, compiler-errors, stack

why this little piece of code is giving illegal start of type error in line 6 and 10(for loops).... i can't find any unmatched braces...

```
class StackDemo{
    final int size = 10;
    Stack s = new Stack(size);

    //Push charecters into the stack
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        s.push((char)'A'+i);
    }
    //pop the stack untill its empty
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        System.out.println("Pooped element "+i+" is "+ s.pop());
    }
}
```

I have the class Stack implemented,

Comment: Offtopic, but you should check difference between popped and pooped. lol.

Comment: Can i delete my own question? The amount of stupidity i put into making that mistake.....ugghhhhhhhh

Comment: @m.souvik you can't. Since there are answers here. Next time before hurry to ask an question. Please take some time to figure out the issue by yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `for` loop in class level. Put them inside a `method` or a `block`

Also `java.util.Stack` in `Java` don't have such constructor.

It should be

```
Stack s = new Stack()
```

Another issue

```
s.push(char('A'+i))// you will get Unexpected Token error here
```

Just change it to

```
s.push('A'+i);
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use for loop inside a class body, you need to put them in some kind of method.

```
class StackDemo{
final int size = 10;
Stack s = new Stack(size);
public void run(){
   //Push charecters into the stack
   for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
       s.push(char('A'+i));
   }
   //pop the stack untill its empty
   for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
      System.out.println("Pooped element "+i+" is "+ s.pop());
   }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just write code in a class, you need a method for that:

```
class StackDemo{
    static final int size = 10;
    static Stack s = new Stack(size);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Push charecters into the stack
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            s.push(char('A'+i));
        }
        //pop the stack untill its empty
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            System.out.println("Pooped element "+i+" is "+ s.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

The method `main` is the entry point for a Java application. The JVM will call that method on program startup. Please notice that I've added the code word `static` to your variables, so they could be directly used in the static method `main`.