# Why am I receiving errors on Java array assignment?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to assign int literals to certian indexs of the array. I keep  getting errors from the compiler. This [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) seems to suggest That I have done this correctly. 
Here is the code:

```
public class Mytest {
    int[] jim = new int[9];
    jim[0] = 77;
}
```

Compiler Errors:

```
Mytest.java:5: error: ']' expected
    jim[0] = 77;
        ^
Mytest.java:5: error: ';' expected
    jim[0] = 77;
         ^
Mytest.java:5: error: illegal start of type
    jim[0] = 77;
           ^
Mytest.java:5: error: <identifier> expected
    jim[0] = 77;
            ^
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the article again, the first 2 lines of code in particular.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502235/error-illegal-start-of-type)'s a duplicate, I don't have votes left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your assignment statement to a valid location. This could be a method, a constructor, or an initialization block.

```
public class Mytest {
    int[] jim = new int[9];
    // Using an initialization block
    {
        jim[0] = 77;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put them into a method or into a constructor, which is a 'special' method.

You have to put those lines inside your main method, if 'Mytest' is your main class, or in any other method you create for that, inside that class.